# Checkers jump moves (in SFML)

Tags: c++, sfml

I started coding a few weeks ago and trying out a checker-game right now. I made a class called "figure" and then an array (figure Figure[value]).
I created a 2D field-array in main.cpp and filled it with the numbers for each Figure[]. E.G.:

```
(main.cpp)
figure Figure[33];    //Figure-array

for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++)
{
    Figure[i].id = i;
}

int field[7][7] = {   // (I messed the ID's up a little, just ignore it
                    {0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0},
                    {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}
                    {14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20},
                    {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27},
                    {0, 0, 28, 29, 30, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 31, 32, 33, 0, 0}
                  };

for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++)  //Field gets filled with figure-values {
    for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
    {
        if (field[y][x] != 0)
        {
            Figure[field[y][x] - 1].setPosition(Vector2i(x + 1, y + 1)); 
        }
    } 
}
```

Now I want to make an update function to make them jump over each other etc. My problem here is that i dont know is how to do this properly, I dont know how to write this function completely.Here is what i have already:

```
(Updatefunction)
void figure::update(int (&field)[7][7], RenderWindow &window) {

Vector2i mouseCoords;
mouseCoords.x = int(Mouse::getPosition(window).x / 114);
mouseCoords.y = int(Mouse::getPosition(window).y / 85);

if ((field[mouseCoords.y][mouseCoords.x] != 0) && (Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left)))
{
    if ((field[mouseCoords.y][mouseCoords.x] != 0) && !(Mouse::isButtonPressed(Mouse::Left)))
    {
            selected = true; //selected defined in figure.h
    }

}

Vector2i newMouseCoords;
newMouseCoords.x = int(Mouse::getPosition(window).x / 114);
newMouseCoords.y = int(Mouse::getPosition(window).y / 85);

if (selected = true)
{
    if ((newMouseCoords.x == mouseCoords.x + 2) && (field[newMouseCoords.y][newMouseCoords.x + 2] != 0))
    {

    }
}
```

}

I dont know how to continue here, tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You've got some semantic errors in your C++ code, too. `selected = true` in that last `if` statement is going to assign `true` to `selected`, and will always evaluate to `true` (since the assignment operator returns the value that was assigned). Change this line to `if (selected == true)`, or more idiomatically, change it to `if (selected)`, then you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided all your code, so I can't give you an exact solution (and your full listing would probably be too long, and make the question unreadable if you included it, so I wouldn't recommend that).

Here's how I would solve it, given what your existing code looks like:

1. Do something in this function to handle the appropriate turns. Don't let a player move a piece that isn't theirs.
2. In your first click check, don't just set a non-piece-specific boolean value to true. Store the "selected piece" in some other variable instead.
3. Before your second click check, see if the "selected piece" variable is set (maybe check if it is not `null` - depends on how you define that variable).
4. Inside the body of your second click check, see if the target position for the selected piece constitutes a valid move. If it doesn't, then display an error to the user.
5. If the second click check constitutes a valid move, then update the board:

   1. Move the piece, capture any pieces it jumped over, king if necessary
   2. If there is another double-jump move that is possible (there might be two double jumps they could choose from), then allow the player to choose another move. This means more "if" blocks...
   3. If there is a double-jump, then allow the person to back out of the move, since they haven't completed it yet. Uncapture their first jump.
   4. Depending on how strict you are being on the rules, don't allow a person to choose not to do a double-jump. Some checkers rules make capture mandatory if it is possible.
   5. Once all moves are complete, then switch the variable that keeps track of whose turn it is, and unset the "selected piece" variable.
6. Handle the game end check, and the game over state. This probably should be done after a move.